# Create a top 3 leader table with tie'd scores

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm currently trying to do a leader board based on 4 metrics, i kept it simple doing `Select TOP (3)` from my table ordering by largest to smallest. Then added in a `ROW_NUMBER()` to give the 1, 2, 3. Then aggregating it up i created a case when to assign 100 to No1, 50 to No2 and 25 to No3.

Issue I've got is I get a tie for some of the scores. it then uses the next field to sort and drops one down to 50 points when I want joint to both have 100. Hope i've explained this OK?

I'm sure there's a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: Have you looked at using RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER? ROW_NUMBER will always generate a different value for each row whereas if there's a tie, RANK will give the rows the same value. Use DENSE_RANK if you don't want to skip numbers (e.g. RANK - a tie for first place would give you values like 1, 1, 3, 4... whereas DENSE_RANK would give 1, 1, 2, 3...)

Comment: [This manual page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx "Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)") shows how various ranking functions work (basically, serves as an illustration of @Patrick's suggestion).

Comment: Ok so i switched it to dense rank and thats all great, i've now done a cte to rank by month's. Do you know how I can rank by 2 fields? For example for March, get the top 3 of department 1, then dept 2 ect.